# how do I combine a single row with it's own index with an unstacked multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have a dataframe created by the following code:

```
dfHubR2I=dfHubPV2.loc[dfHubPV2['Ind'].dt.year == year, :].groupby(['SHOP_CODE', dfHubPV2['Ind'].dt.month])['R2I'].agg(['median']).fillna('-')
dfHubR2I=dfHubR2I['median'].unstack('SHOP_CODE')
dfHubR2I=dfHubR2I.iloc[:date.month-1]
dfHubR2I
```

It looks like this:

```
shop code     A     B    C    D   All Shops
ind
1            23     34   23   56      34
2            13     23   45   47      34
3            56     67   42   85      57
4            3       3    2   6       46
```

where ind is months and the letters are different shops

I then got the median across all the shops for each month from this code:

```
dfHubR2Imonthallshops=dfHubPV2.loc[dfHubPV2['Ind'].dt.year == year, :].groupby([dfHubPV2['Ind'].dt.month])['R2I'].agg(['median']).fillna('-')
dfHubR2Imonthallshops=dfHubR2Imonthallshops.rename(columns={'median':'All Shops'})
dfHubR2Imonthallshops=dfHubR2Imonthallshops.iloc[:date.month-1]
dfHubR2Imonthallshops
```

which looks like this:

```
          A  B C D All shops
median    2  3 4 5    2
```

And I need to append it onto the bigger dataframe as a row but when I try to use pd.concat I get the error InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

I'm assuming it's because the larger dadtaframe has 2 levels but I'm not sure how to go about getting my final desired result:

```
shop code     A     B    C    D  All shops
ind
1            23     34   23   56    34
2            13     23   45   47    34
3            56     67   42   85    57 
4            3       3    2   6     46
YTD          2       3    4    5    2
```

Comment: oops I'm sorry I forgot to switch out the part about median across each month, I fixed that and the picture of the row is correct, I found the median across all shops YTD and THAT is what I want to append to the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do it with an assignment?

`dfHubR2I.loc['YTD', :] = dfHubR2Imonthallshops.loc['median', :]`

Eleonora